# stable-baseline3, gym, train while also step/predict

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

With stable-baselines3 given an agent, we can call "action = agent.predict(obs)". And then with Gym, this would be "new_obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)". (more or less, maybe missed an input or an output).

We also have "agent.learn(10_000)" as an example, yet here we're less involved in the process and don't call the environment.

Looking for a way to train the agent while still calling "env.step". If you wander why, just trying to implement self play (agent and a previous version of it) playing with one environment (for example turns play as Chess).

WKR, Oren.

Answer (score 0):

But why do you need it? If you take a look at the implementation of any `learn` method, you will see it is nothing more than an iteration over time steps calling `collect_rollouts` and `train` with some additional logging and setup at the beginning for, e.g., further saving the agent etc. Your `env.step` is called inside `collect_rollouts`.

I'd better suggest you to write a callback based on [CheckpointCallback](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/callbacks.html#checkpointcallback), which saves your agent (model) after N training steps and then attach this callback to your `learn` call. In your environment you could instantiate each N steps a "new previous" version of your model by calling `ModelClass.load(file)` on the file saved by a callback, so that finally you would be able to select actions of the other player using a self-play in your environment

Comment: Above you have taught me a few things. Among others you suggest maybe to read the code of the learn implementation. Maybe I can just copy it and add my logic. Also you've suggested a callback where I can potentially do the logic I need. I still hope that someone knows even a better way. The issue is with multiplayer environments (PettingZoo), that it does not exactly lean itself toward "agent.learn" for one of the agents. Or I am missing something. I still don't see the light.